# how to move one point in google maps programmatically xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-api

I create one app and using it google maps api. I want move animation one point (for example my location) to the top. please guide me about that because I don't know about that.

I want when click Move button my map moving to top (100px) please tell me how do it?

this is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    double latitudes;
    double longitudes;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self GetMyLocation];

    UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    pinButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-80,self.view.frame.size.height-80, 60, 60);
    [pinButton setTitle:@"Self" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pinButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [pinButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowMyLocation:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *add = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    add.frame = CGRectMake(20,self.view.frame.size.height-80, 60, 60);
    [add setTitle:@"add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [add setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [add addTarget:self action:@selector(Move:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // nokte mohem ine ke baadan ye logitude & latitude default ezafe kon chon shaiad tuie ye sharaiete tokhmi ke hamid esrar dare va ye kasi mariz bood dastresie GPS ro ghat kard

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitudes longitude:longitudes zoom:14];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero  camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [mapView_ setMapType:kGMSTypeNormal];
    self.view = mapView_;
    [mapView_ addSubview:pinButton];
    [mapView_ addSubview:add];

}
- (IBAction)Move:(id)sender{
    //move marker place
}
- (IBAction)ShowMyLocation:(id)sender{

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coor.latitude,coor.longitude);
    marker.title = @"I'm Here";
    marker.snippet = @"Rahnova Co.";
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
- (void) GetMyLocation{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        latitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    }
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitudes longitude:longitudes zoom:14];
    [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of the ways to move inside the Google which is to set the **camera of the Mapview**.

```
- (IBAction)Move:(id)sender{
  //move marker place

  CLLocationCoordinate2D moveToCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);
  //0, 0 are the Coordinates that you wan to,

  GMSCameraPosition *camera =
  [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:moveToCoordinate.latitude
                            longitude:moveToCoordinate.longitude
                                 zoom:14];
  [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

Comment: your code is right and solved my problem. I have one question my friend how to get coordinate(latitude,longitude) that center of the page horizontally and 25% off the top of the page in my map??? because I want when click any marker(pin) I going to this coordinate!!!

Comment: If my answer is correct, pleas upvote and mark as answer. If you have another question, please open a new question, don't ask under the comment. As for marker, you have to use the delegate method **didTapMarker**

Comment: If you don't need to change zoom level, you can simply go [mapView animateToLocation:moveToCoordinate]; :D